# R setorder corrupts original data table 2 generations ago

Tags: r, data.table

What is happening here, that the aplication of setorder results in the original tab having the *N* column not ordered while the other columns are, thus corrputing the data table?

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

colFun <- function(dt, cols, fun){
    for(col in cols){
        dt[[col]] <- dt[[col]] %>% fun()
    }
    # irrelevant manipulations
    return(dt)
}
topRows <- function(dt, n, ncol = 'N'){
    setorderv(dt, ncol, -1)
    # irrelevant manipulations
    return(dt[1:n,])
}


tab <- data.table(
    id = 1005:1001,
    N = 1:5+.01,
    X = c('E','D','C','B','A')
)
tab
#setkey(tab, id)
tab %>% colFun('N', round) %>% topRows(3)
tab
```

Does not happen when the key is set...

Comment: Could be a similar issue as https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5379

Answer (score 2):

Per data.table's help menu:

> In data.table parlance, all set* functions change their input by
> reference. That is, no copy is made at all, other than temporary
> working memory, which is as large as one column.

Additionally,

> If setorder results in reordering of the rows of a keyed data.table,
> then its key will be set to NULL.

I don't think it makes sense to reorder a data.table that has already been keyed since by setting the key you are expecting the table to be sorted by that key in ascending order.

When you call `setorderv`. All it does is sort the columns selected. In this case `N`. However, what appears to be happening here is since both setkey and setorder are done in RAM. The shallow copy from setorder can't determine the original sorting mechanism with setkey. Therefore, setkey gets set to NULL and leading to some very strange results.

You can avoid this by either directly saving dt in the function environment or calling setkey again after setorder.

```
topRows <- function(dt, n, ncol = 'N'){
    dt = setorderv(dt, ncol, -1)
    return(dt[1:n,])
}

# or

topRows <- function(dt, n, ncol = 'N'){
    setorderv(dt, ncol, -1)
    setkey(tab, id)
    return(dt[1:n,])
}

#      id N X
# 1: 1001 5 A
# 2: 1002 4 B
# 3: 1003 3 C
```

Comment: The first colution doesn´t seem to work actually... I resorted to calling 

```topRows <- function(tab, n, ncol = 'N'){
    dt <- copy(tab)
    setorderv(dt, ncol, -1)
    return(dt[1:n,])
}```

Comment: I'm on `purrr v0.3.4` and `data.table v1.14.2` and both solutions seem to work on my end.